# aws ec2 get-console-output prints nothing to the screen

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am creating an aws ec2 instance using [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html), and I can't find any information on troubleshooting my issue, or any evidence that anyone else has even experienced this!

I used an IAM user with admin permissions to set up an ec2 instance, and when I run

```
$> aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id <my-ec2-id>
```

a blank line is output, followed by

```
'Output'
```

and nothing else!

According to the tutorial, this command would enable me to see the remote RSA fingerprint to verify I'm making the right connection.

I can log into my ec2 instance just fine (though I suppose without the previous step there's no way to be absolutely sure).

Additionally, the IAM user I'm working with is not my CLI's default user, and I set up a profile to handle it.  But if I try

```
$> aws ec2 get-console-output --profile <user-profile> --instance-id <my-ec2-id>
```

I still get the same results as before.  The maddening thing is that I have solved this problem before, but I can't remember how.

Comment: is it a Windows instance or Linux instance?

Comment: Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09.1 x86_64 HVM GP2

Comment: You don't even get the instance-id and the timestamp?

Comment: I only get a blank line, then 'Output', then the prompt appears again.  I wish I got more feedback, though I'm thinking it may be an issue with my credentials, as I'm getting "AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials" when I run 'aws ec2 describe-instances' using the user's profile I set up.  Still, why wouldn't I get a similar message with get-console-output?

Comment: @Joel You're correct, get-console-output doesn't actually state if the permissions are invalid. I've raised an issue on the CLI GitHub repo for it. I'll add an answer with some details on how to debug/identify this issue, to make this easier for future users.

Comment: Just to clarify - newer CLI (1.9) does state that the instance ID is invalid, but older (at least 1.7) doesn't.

Comment: Ah.. Thank you! This helps, though I'm still tracking down the answer as to why my user with administration privileges can't get info on the ec2 instance.

Comment: Got it.. in case anyone reads this far.. even though I checked and re-checked my access key and secret (could only see the last four characters, but it all matched), deleting them and creating new ones for my admin user solved the issue.  This may be unrelated, but my new ones only contained alphanumeric characters, while the old secret had a slash and maybe another special character.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain AWS CLI operations may not explicitly state if the credentials are invalid or if users are lacking the roles/permissions to access the resources defined. In this case, it is likely due to the Access Credentials being invalid - and you can verify this with a `describe-instances` or similar command.

In older versions of the CLI (~1.7), in order to easier debug this, you can use the --debug argument, such as:

```
> aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id i-<id> --debug

<Errors><Error><Code>InvalidInstanceID.NotFound</Code><Message>The instance ID 'i-e7bffa43' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors>
```

In newer versions of the CLI (1.9) this particular argument gives a bit more detail in its error:

```
> aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id i-<id>

A client error (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) occurred when calling the GetConsoleOutput operation: The instance ID 'i-<id>' does not exist
```